# Создание ярлыка в Ubuntu с root правами

Tags: linux, ubuntu, desktop

Создал ярлык, работает, но нужны рут права! Как добавить выполнение от рута?
вот что лежит в smartgit.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=SmartGit
Comment=
GenericName=
Keywords=git; smart;
Exec=sh /home/ross/smartgit/bin/smartgit.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=/home/ross/smartgit/bin/smartgit-128.png
Path=
Categories=
NoDisplay=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте добавить вызов `gksudo` в эту строку:

```
Exec=sh /home/ross/smartgit/bin/smartgit.sh
```

чтоб она выглядела примерно так:

```
Exec=gksudo sh /home/ross/smartgit/bin/smartgit.sh
```

---

тогда при «вызове» этого *desktop-файла* должен появиться диалог (его создаёт программа `gksudo`) с предложением ввести пароль для подтверждения полномочий пользователя.

Comment: не понимаю почему, но когда добавил gksudo, вместо запуска программы открываеться корневая папка программы

Comment: а в эмуляторе терминала такая команда работает?

Comment: проблема решена! первое нужно установить gksu (sudo apt-get install gksu, может кому надо будет), а второе, прописывать нужно не gksudo, а просто gksu, тогда действительно перед запуском выскочит окошко для пароля! Спасибо!

Comment: @RossFilipchuk, учитывая, что `/usr/bin/gksudo` — это всего лишь *symlink* на `/usr/bin/gksu`, наблюдаемая вами картина выглядит весьма странно. может быть, пользователь, который щёлкает по вашему desktop-файлу, не имеет полномочий на использование `sudo`? тогда понятно, что нужно `su` и пароль *root-а*. / кстати, у этой программы (gksu, она же gksudo) есть пара опций: `--su-mode` и `--sudo-mode`, смысл которых понятен из их названий.