# Ярлык или батник в Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lubuntu

Начал изучать Linux. Установил Lubuntu 16.04. У меня есть росшаренная папка на Windows-машине. Как мне написать скрипт (типа DOS-батника) и разместить его на рабочий стол Lubuntu, что бы по необходимости, нажать на него и выполнится команда:

```
mount.cifs //192.168.1.2/general /mnt/general -o username=user,password=12345
```

и такой же самый "ярлык" с командой:

```
umount /mnt/general
```

Та и вообще как создавать ярлыки на рабочий стол, например для офисного документа (электронная таблица). Что бы "далекий" пользователь могла сразу его запускать? 
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: вызов упомянутых программ требует полномочий суперпользователя. это уже совершенно другой вопрос. если вы хотите получить на него ответ, то сформулируйте и напишите его отдельным вопросом.

Comment: вообще-то новый вопрос писать не стоит. ответ [уже есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432696/178576). поэтому просто уберите, пожалуйста, конкретику, сделав вопрос более абстрактным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

для выполнения команды надо создать файл с произвольным именем и суффиксом `.desktop` такого минимального содержимого (возможно, некоторые строки даже лишние):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=какое-нибудь имя
Exec=команда (с параметрами)
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

---

чтобы он появился на «рабочем столе» некоего пользователя, надо поместить его в соответствующий каталог. путь к этому каталогу можно получить, выполнив от имени целевого пользователя команду:

```
$ xdg-user-dir DESKTOP
```

пример вывода:

```
/home/user/Desktop
```

---

вроде бы, нынче некоторые «особо умные» de (desktop environments) начинают «вставлять палки в колёса», сообщая какой-то бред про «запуск недоверенной программы» (или что-то в этом духе), если у данного файла не стоит битов исполнимости. потому, на всякий случай, лучше их поставить:

```
$ chmod +x файл
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня kubuntu, так что для Lubuntu детали могут отличаться.

На рабочем столе нажать правой кнопкой, выбрать Создать -> Текстовый файл.

В этом файле вводим текст

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.2/general /mnt/general -o username=user,password=12345
```

Сохранить, закрыть.

Далее на этом файле нажимаем правой кнопкой мыши, выбираем Свойства. На вкладке Права выставляем флаг Является выполняемым.

В общем все. У меня заработало (команда конечно же была другая).

Ярлыки для документов на рабочем столе создаются также как и в Windows, при помощи технологии Drag&Drop (перетаскивание мышью). У меня для создания ярлыка, а не перемещения файла, потребовалось нажать кнопку Alt.

Comment: sudo будет требовать ввод пароля! нужно либо использовать гуишный gksudo вместо него, либо выставить при помощи visudo беспарольный доступ юзеру.